# Ошибка подключения CSS файлов

Tags: html, css

Html не видит стили. Т.е подключено все правильно. Вот код. В чем может быть причина?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr" >
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/font/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/font/pfdinpro.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Cufon.replace("#page #header #phone");
Cufon.replace(".menumainmenu li a");
Cufon.replace("h1");
Cufon.replace("h2");
</script>
  <head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/template.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css" type="text/css" />
    <!-- вывод метатегов -->
      <base href="http://orleanfrance.myjino.ru/" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="author" content="Super User" />
  <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" />
  <title>Статьи</title>
  <link href="/templates/likom25/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
  <script src="js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('load', function() {
                new JCaption('img.caption');
            });
  </script>

<link rel="icon" href="/templates/likom25/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/template/likom25/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

  </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr" >

 <head>
    <title>Статьи</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="author" content="Super User" /> 
    <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" />

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/font/cufon-yui.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="/font/pfdinpro.font.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.replace("#page #header #phone"); Cufon.replace(".menumainmenu li a"); Cufon.replace("h1"); Cufon.replace("h2"); </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/system.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/template.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <base href="http://orleanfrance.myjino.ru/" />   
    <link href="/templates/likom25/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />

    <script src="js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> window.addEvent('load', function() { new JCaption('img.caption'); }); </script>

    <link rel="icon" href="/templates/likom25/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/template/likom25/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

</head>

    <body>
        <h1>УРАААААААААААААААААА! РАБОТАЕТ!!!!!!!!!!!!</h1>
    </body>

</html>
```

Проверил работает! Проверьте! файлы css должны быть в папке css. Скрипты должны быть в head

Comment: :) файлы в папочке css. только из всей папочки он видит один файл template.css... :(

Comment: я создал файл - system.css - рыботает